# c# string.CompareOrdinal vs operator ==

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I want to compare two strings in a `linq` expression. Do I take advantage if I use `string.CompareOrdinal or is it the same?

```
list.Where(str1 => string.CompareOrdinal(str1, str2) == 0);
list.Where(str1 => str1 == str2);
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Blogposts? Benchmarks? Source code?

Answer (score 3):

According to benchmarks done by someone else, `string.CompareOrdinal` can be *slightly* faster than `==` when doing *a lot* of comparisons:

> Most of the board remained green up through 10,000 comparisons and didn’t register any time.
>
> At the 100,000 and 1,000,000 marks, things started to get a bit more interesting in terms of time differences.
>
> `String.CompareOrdinal` was the constant superstar. What surprised me is for the case-insensitive comparisons, `String.CompareOrdinal` outperformed most other methods by a whole decimal place.
>
> For case sensitive comparisons, most programmers can probably stick with the “==” operator.

-- [The Curious Consultant: Fastest Way to Compare Strings in C# .Net](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-compare-strings)

---

Note, though, that we are talking about a total difference of 3 milliseconds for 100,000 case-sensitive string comparisons, and that no measurable differences have been observed for 10,000 and 1,000,000 comparisons.

Thus, is **very** unlikely that this difference is relevant to your application (especially if you are using LINQ-to-objects), so the more readable `==` should be preferred.